# hiding/removing selected from select option list for multiple select tags with same list

Tags: jquery

let's say i have 4 select tags that uses the same option choices. i wanted to remove the selected options from the choices. currently i tried this code:

```
    function connect(val)
{
    $(".option").show();
    $(".selectbox").each(function(i) { 
        var obj = $("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
        alert(obj);
        if($(this).val() != "") obj.remove();

    });
}
```

i have this for the select tags:

```
for()
{
<select id = "sc" name = "connect_array[]" class="input-select" onchange = "connect(this.value)">
for()
{
<option></option>
}
</select>
}
```

But what actually happens is the it only removes the options of the first select and the first select ends up with no choices when all choices where chosen by the other select tags, also you can still see the full choices in the other select tags.

thank you.

Comment: I'm failing to see what PHP has to do with this.

Comment: Not client-side, there isn't; and *client-side* is where jQuery works.

Comment: `.selectbox` and `.option` don't match any elements that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

try this, all your selects need to have class="selectbox"

```
$(".selectbox").change(function(){
    var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    $(".selectbox").each(function(i){
        if (selectedIndex != i){
            $("option", this).each(function(){
                if (myVal == $(this).val()) $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I re-read my code, and it would have deleted even the one you just selected. so i modified it so it should keep the option that was selected and go through and find any others and delete those.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectbox').change(function(){
        var selected_val = $(this+"option:selected").val();
        $(".selectbox").each(function(i) { 
            $(this+'option[value="'+selected_val+'"]').remove();
        });
    }
```